# Why Goku super saiyan blue's power up aura glows different colors inside lately?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

This is Goku super saiyan blue's power up against Hit. Is this his normal super saiyan blue aura or those yellow, white and green colors inside arent blue in purpose, like a signal he's close to get a new stage or something? I think something similar happened with his aura against merged Zamasu

[image: Goku vs Hit round 2]

[image: Power up and kamehameha]

Comment: In that episode it wasn't just his aura it was his aura clashing with Hit's time skip ability. Whiss sister pointed out that his ability allows him to make a parallel mini world with the time he skips Goku's energy was pushing into that world. Causing the mix of energy.